# magento 1.9.3 Launguage switcher stuck in specific language

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view, language

I have a Magento store v1.9.3.8 and the store has 2 store views: Arabic and English, the Arabic is the default one and when I switch the language to English it works fine, but when I click on any other page it returns to Arabic. How to fix this?

Comment: On which page it works fine? Did you set locale in admin for each store views?

Comment: i can switch language to english  in any page .. but when i go to another page it redirect automatically to arabic

Comment: That means magento not saving your current store view when you are changing. Try it in private browser.

Comment: yes it works fine in private window.Thanks a lot

Comment: yes sure go ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is something related to caching or browser related as its not saving your current store to session.

Either you can try to clean the browser cache or try it in private browser.

Hope this helps!